# How to set or change a phone number programmatically?

Tags: applications, calls, hardware

I know how to get or read a phone number. But how to set or change one?

I want to change it in such a way that other application installed on my phone would **read** it as a custom number that I had set.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The phone number can not be set. On rooted devices you may take the number apps can get but the actual phone number can not be changed as it is managed by the SIM card, a mini computer on its own you don't have access to.

Comment: @Robert re-read my question

Comment: It doesn't matter how often I read your question, it stays the same. May be your understanding of a custom number is different than mine but you can not set a custom number in Android so it is not easy to understand what you want. You should consider updating your question and describe in detail what you are trying to do. Also please add details about the used phone, Android version and if the phone is rooted.

Comment: @Robert. No. I'm right, you're wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter who is right or wrong. If the users on this site don't understand what you want to do won't get an answer...

Comment: @Robert. No. I'm right, you're wrong